# Nvidia 750ti login freeze on (K/L/X/Unity)ubuntu, CentOS and OpenSuse

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde, opensuse, nvidia

I am trying to switch my desktop to a stable Linux distro, so I tried all flavors of Ubuntu(Debian), CentOS and Opensuse. However, despite the differences between distros the same freeze after login bug still exists. (Shell works perfectly)

The desktop environment that I used were Gnome, KDE and Unity. All of them have the freeze after login problem.

I have tried to fix it by installing Nvidia's proprietary driver and "Additional Drivers" in Ubuntu, both of these didn't fix the problem. The problem with Additional Drivers option is that it won't let me select to the Nvidia Driver, it has the option there but whenever I click apply/save it turns back to the X org nouveau driver. Also after some research it appears upgrading the kernel will fix it so I upgraded to 4.8 the latest yet still no luck...

Computer Spec:

- AMD FX8350
- Nvidia GeForce 750ti
- 8GB of RAM
- 1TB WD
- Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P ATX AM3+ Motherboard

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
05:07.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
```

Anyone have any idea how to get Nvidia 750ti to work on these Linux(s) or any Linux. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `lspci` or `lshw`

Comment: Added the output of lspci! Thanks for telling me.

Comment: After making sure you dont need VGA switcharoo, try my answer below.

Comment: I don't think I need VGASwitcharoo since I only have 1 GPU. From what I researched VGA switcharoo has to do with multiple GPUs. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks. Also I'll be trying your answer below.

Comment: You are correct, which is why I asked for the extra output.

Comment: ok thanks for confirming, also in order for me to try your answer below do I need to uninstall my previously installed nvidia drivers? Or just anything I need to do to prepare for it. Is it preferable to have a fresh install?

Comment: I would just so you know you're starting "clean."

Comment: Ok, I'll get a fresh install now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

1. `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target`
2. `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
3. `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target`

After isolating graphical.target, let me know what you see.I can't tell you why, but it sounds as if the nouveau driver isn't completely uninstalled. As an extra step, you may want to [blacklist the modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau).

As per comments, you now need to update the video BIOS.  Note: HOWTO: [Flash BIOS, The Ubuntu Way](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318789) may help, but you'll be using video BIOS updates, instead of plain BIOS updates.

Comment: After the third step the ubuntu gnome loading page showed up for half a second and send me back to the tty that I was at. Interestingly the tty session is flashing...

Comment: Also it won't let me execute any commands either, sort of like console freeze except that its flashing.

Comment: That confirms that the drivers are installed correctly, and you need a VGA BIOS Update.  Contact the vendor of your Card.  Ask if they have any flashable BIOS updates for that particular card.  If they say no, you're out of luck.

Comment: I checked before that the BIOS for my motherboard is upped to date. Also the screen stopped flashing and is allowing me to execute commands. I'll try to blacklist the modules and do a restart see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Not your motherboard BIOS, your Graphics card BIOS

Comment: oh... OK I'll check.

Comment: No luck... all the BIOS Drivers for my GPU are for Windows... Also after restarting my machine, it won't even bring me to the login page anymore, its blinking like all these [ OK ] started blah blah blah messages.

Comment: You need to contact the Vendor of your Graphics card, ie, eVGA etc and ask if they have a way to update the VGA BIOS via linux, otherwise you need to install Windows, apply the updates, then install linux.  This is not a Driver issue.  I've had this same problem.  It's a video BIOS issue, i.e. the video BIOS is too old for the nvidia driver

Comment: Oh ok, I see thank you so much for the help I very much appreciate it!